# Which React lifecycle method is a good replacement for componentWillRecieveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have heard of `getDerivedStateFromProps` but it does not work how I want it to.

I have this code:

```
class App extends Component {
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        console.log("Get derived state from props called");
        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({})}>Change State</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Clicking the button calls `getDerivedStateFromProps`. This is not what I need. I want a function that is called **only when new props are received**. When internal state changes, this function should not be called.

I intend to use this in a modal form scenario. When the component receives an object as a prop, the component should translate this object into a form, then place that form into the state. If I use `getDerivedStateFromProps`, since it is called in every `this.setState()`, it would not reflect the changes in the form since whenever the user types, a `this.setState()` is fired, and instead of the changes being set into the state, the initial object is.

Which React lifecycle method should I use?

Comment: If you only need the object from props as the initial state, then use it either on the constructor (better) or on `componentDidMount`. According to the React guys (Dan Abramov mostly) using `componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` to keep the state in sync with some props is a gateway to bugs, which is why they set on this behaviour for `getDerivedStateFromProps` (also because they need it for future features), so you'll have to refactor around it.

Comment: Yes, but what about if the use wishes to modify another object? The form is designed to be reused of course, you can modify multiple objects. The state has to reflect whichever object the parent passes.

Comment: You can give the state you want to modify on the component constructor and work with the component's internal state from there, and only update the parent component's state when you submit the form. Or have the child component keep no state at all and give it callbacks to update the parent comp. state. Either way, syncronizing an object in internal state with the same one coming from props is an unnecessary hassle, you would have to check for all the properties of said object before updating

Comment: I can't. The constructor is invoked only when the component is mounted. The component is always mounted, it's the object prop that changes over time.

Comment: Then keep both the prop object and the state object in the state, and compare them in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. There you can update the internal state object as needed and render only the state object (not the prop object). Like I said, a bit cumbersome but there is no alternative lifecycle method that fires "only when new props are received", because the context in which props are "new" compared to previous ones is not always the same (every time render fires you get "new props", that doesn't mean that their values changed)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this problem depending on different use cases.

1. If new props are added, those new props can be checked in the `Child` component and user defined functions can be called in case the new object exists.
2. `getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state, prevProps)` is a static method and `this` does not exist in the same, which means that you'll have to return a state based on various conditions. That is, let it work on default on most cases. On cases where you want to alter its functionality, place checks and return the modified state.

Hope it answers :)

Comment: I mentioned getDerivedStateFromProps in the post I made. It is not what I need.